# How to create material design layout in xml file?

Tags: android, xml, material-design, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I want to create xml in material design like below picture,how to do like that in material design?[image]

Comment: I don't think this is android's material design design, it's one of those for web...

Comment: No this is material design only... please check here https://www.google.co.in/design/spec/layout/structure.html#structure-ui-regions

Comment: this is new design, i know how to do it in kitkat, but material design is different... that's way i asked... please help me if u know... thanks for your comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code...

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="192dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="32dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />
```

Let me know if it works for you...
And do mark it as answer so that it will be useful to others...
You will get something like this...
P.S. I am using cardView library and support design library so don't forget to put the below lines in your build.gradle file...

```
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.0'
```

[image: You will get something like this]

Comment: Error:(24) No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_collapseMode' , 'layout_scrollFlags','expandedTitleMarginEnd','expandedTitleMarginStart', 'contentScrim','expandedTitleMarginBottom', I am getting this error when i rebuild.. can u send any sample for me...i am very confusing this designs

Comment: Now it is working fine... can u send that gradle dependencies i think problem is there only... now some what working fine with this error.. the following classes could not found... android.support.v7.widget.cardView in xml file... fix build path,edit xml,create class

Comment: how to change the background color of cardView... when i type for background no option is coming

Comment: when i try to drag textview inside cardview it is not coming?  if u know can u share with me? how to add textview inside cardview?